# Best alternatives to jQuery on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Well, I wish we could list the best alternatives to jQuery for use with AngularJS, taking into account compatibility with AngularJS and the ability to manipulate the styles (css), besides the possibility of using effects such as fadeIn, fadeOut, slideDown, slideUp, etc.

As based on the response to comment propose to take into consideration the following factors:

- Compatibility with AngularJS.
- Handling of styles.
- Handling events.
- Effects
- ...

> The idea is that this thread is helpful when alternatives to jQuery to
>   work with AngulaJS.

Comment: jqlite ring and bells?

Comment: The idea of AngularJS is to not directly touch the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: Use angular for all of this, not jquery.

First of all, you can(**must**) do all of this with angular. Or there is no point to use angular at all. I mean this is very bad practice to manipulate dom directly or do other jquery-style things. Angular provide much more modern approach for all of this things (via built-in and custom directives and etc.).

As the second point - what's wrong with jquery? You're able to use jquery with angular. It's a common practice, because some of third-party libs have a jquery dependency.

And the last one - Angular have built-in *jqlite* inside, so you're able to do some stuff in this way

As a light-weigth alternatives to jquery you can use [zeptojs](http://zeptojs.com/). But again - this is weird. And I didn't sure how much zepto is better than jqlite.

And as a last point - you can do everything with pure js. But you should keep in mind point about browser's support

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would just use vanilla javascript to do the DOM manipulation. `Styles` and `events` would be possible within angular.

And as far as effects are concerned, a simple library like [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) can help!

So in short,

> Compatibility with AngularJS. 
> - **Its vanilla Javascript so no issues here**
>    Handling of styles. 
> - **By handling of styles, if you mean using conditional styles, it could be accomplished by angular's ng-class**
>    Handling DOM. 
>  - **Most of the DOM manipulations can be handled by pure javascript. If you still need a lightweight library go for one of these** 
>   [ryejs](http://ryejs.com/) or [nodelist](https://www.sitepoint.com/dom-manipulation-with-nodelist-js/) or use [jqlite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) that comes bundled with angular
>    Handling events. 
> - **As you are going to be using angularJs, I presume you would be using angular's event model.**
>    Effects 
> - **Definitely** [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)

Comment: animate.css thanks!